# How I can use a global and single instance of a TIdTCPClient in a Windows Service for logging?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I'm using the TIdTCPServer and TIdTCPClient components to comunicate a Windows Service with a VCL application (to send a log), all is working fine but since the service is multi-thread, every time that I send a log (a message string) to the VCL application I need to create a new instance of the component (TIdTCPClient) in the service. So the Question is How I can avoid this and use only one unique instance of the  `TIdTCPClient` component in ther wiundows service side?

Comment: If your service is used only for logging client messages, why don't you instead use `TIdSysLogServer`/`TIdSysLog`? They provide standards compliant logging protocol [RFC 3164](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt) and it's rather simple to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdTCPClient` works just fine across thread boundaries, all you have to do is create a single instance and serialize access to it so that multiple threads cannot send messages at the exact same time and accidentally overlap each other.

I would suggest moving the `TIdTCPClient` to its own dedicated thread, one which monitors the connection state and can reconnect automatically if the server goes down, gets restarted, etc.  Have your worker threads put messages into a thread-safe queue, such as `TIdThreadSafeStringList`, and then have the `TIdTCPClient` check that queue periodically and send it as needed.  That way, your worker threads are not accessing the `TIdTCPClient` directly, and during times when the connection is down it can still gather messages for sending when the connection is reestablished.

On the app side, if it can only ever accept 1 connection at a time, from the service, then using `TIdTCPServer` might be a little overkill.  You might consider using `TIdSimpleServer` instead.